# If you execute the code below, the output will be 8; however, I feel it should be 10. Can anyone explain what goes on here?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Why does this output 8, shouldn't the output be 10?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A 2 + 3
#define B 2 

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    printf("%d\n", A * B);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how macros are expanded?

Comment: You will get surprised if swapping `A` and `B`...

Comment: Now I understand why in social media, they post things like "What is the result of 3 + 9 * 2  ?"

Comment: Everything is here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html

Comment: It is all about **precedence** ! move on...

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス it's just a misunderstanding of macro expansion, I'm sure OP understands arithmetic precedence.

Comment: @RyanHaining hope so !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why parenthesis in macros are important.

Macros do a simple text substitution.  So after macro processing, your code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    printf("%d\n", 3 + 9 * 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Because multiplication has higher precedence, the multiplication happens first, so the result will be 21.

By puttings parenthesis in the macro, you'll have less surprises:

```
#define A (3 + 9)
#define B (2)
```

This results in:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    printf("%d\n", (3 + 9) * (2));
    return 0;
}
```

This will output 24.

Answer (score 4):

`#define` preprocessor directives are just text replacement. `A` and `B` are not variables, as such your `printf` becomes

```
printf("%d\n", 2 + 3 * 2);
```

which is 8, as 2*3 equals 6, add 2 equals 8.

To solve this problem and get `10`, put `()` around your directive

```
#define A (2 + 3)
#define B 2
```

This will cause your `printf` to expand to

```
printf("%d\n", (2 + 3) * 2);
```

To see how the preprocessor expands things before compilation you can pass the `-E` flag to `gcc` or `clang`

However, a better solution would be to use `const int` or `enum` for these constants.

```
const int A = 2 + 3;
const int B = 2;

// or
enum { A = 2 + 3, B = 2 };
```

Comment: Sorry I realized I questioned it wrong*
But I understood what you mean.
Thanks

Comment: @RyanHaining My pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Well in the order it executes, your're doing 9*2 + 3. I'm not sure how your're getting either or those numbers, because it should be 21.

Answer (score 0):

The macro expands as `printf("%d\n", 3 + 9 * 2);` thus the output is 21, nor 8 neither 10.

Answer (score 0):

Macro expansion occurs in the 4th phase of **preprocessing**:

> 4. Preprocessing directives are executed, **macro invocations are expanded**, and _Pragma unary operator expressions are executed.(...)

So each macro will be expanded exactly to its definition `A` -> `3 + 9`  and `B` ->  `2`

resulting `printf("%d\n", 3 + 9 * 2);`

Now comes the role of compiler to analyze the expression syntactically and semantically and during compile time probably it will be evaluated to 21 based on the precedence operator of C language.

```
movl    $.LC1, %edi //first argument of printf "%d\n"
movl    $0, %eax    // second argument of printf 21
call    printf
```